# AngularJS $http.post inside function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service

I am using AngularJS and inside a service I have this:

```
var fn = {
    test: function() {
        $http.post(...)
        .success(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            return response;
        })
    }
}

this.testPostCall = function (id) {
   console.log(fn.test());
};
```

In the controller testPostCall is undefined, in fact in the console the first output that I get is undefined and the second one is the correct JSON response.

Do you know why is undefined inside the controller ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are doing an **[asynchronous procedure not a synchronous one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748175/asynchronous-vs-synchronous-execution-what-does-it-really-mean)**. As indicated in the **[`$http` documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)**:

> The $http API is based on the deferred/promise APIs exposed by the **[$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)**
>   service

Your code is actually showing the correct behaviour, this is because the `fn.test()` function does not return anything and therefore evaluates to `undefined`. If you want to access the data received from your test function, then you have to return the `$http.post()` itself.

It should be something like this:

```
var fn = {
    test: function() {
        return $http.post(...);
    }
};

fn.test().success(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

[**EXAMPLE**](http://plnkr.co/edit/0FO0Bs7EEAt6L3ZkgNox?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

Your process is totally Wrong . try this way

**Service**

```
var myModule = angular.module('myModule', []);
myModule.factory('serviceId', function () {
    var shinyNewServiceInstance = {
        test: test
    };
    // factory function body that constructs shinyNewServiceInstance
    return shinyNewServiceInstance;

    function test() {
        $http.post(...)
            .success(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                return response;
            })
    }
});
```

**Controller**

```
myModule.controller('TestController', ['$scope', 'serviceId',
    function ($scope, serviceId) {
        $scope.greeting = 'Hola!';
        $scope.Test = Test;

        function Test() {

            console.log(serviceId.test());
        }
    }
]);
```